# Please provide a practical example of how/why you use the SinkOf and SinkType in Swift (part of standard library)?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming

These are used heavily in the Swift implementation of ReactiveCocoa and any other functional reactive library I bump into so appear to be of interest from that perspective.

It essentially appears to be a struct wrapping a generic value, but this is obviously too simplistic an interpretation. The types have some comments in the swift standard library but I found them a little too vague and google yields little.

Answer (score 7):

I think it helps to think of sinks as the counterpart of generators.

A generator is basically a function of `(Void -> T)`, where `T` is the type of the thing you're generating.  `GeneratorType` is a protocol that allows structs and classes, etc to act as generators, by giving that function a name: `next() -> T`.  This is handy, because the generator function takes no arguments, so to produce a useful sequence of values, you need a place to keep track of some state between invocations.  `Generator<T>` is a generic base type that conforms to the `GeneratorType` protocol, and you can inherit from it to implement your own `GeneratorType`.

So, back to sinks.  A sink is the inverse of a generator, meaning it's a function of `(T -> Void)`.  It also has an associated protocol `SinkType`, which lets structs and classes act as sinks by defining the sink function as `put(T)`.  And there's a base implementation `SinkOf<T>`, which you can use directly without subtyping by passing in an implementation of the `put` function as a closure.  Since the sink function returns `Void`, it's less likely to need internal state, but if you do, you can inherit from `SinkOf` or implement `SinkType` on your own class/struct.

So `SinkOf` doesn't exactly wrap a generic value so much as it wraps a function that takes a generic value and does something with it.  In the forthcoming ReactiveCocoa 3 rewrite, they're used to replace the RAC 2 concept of a "subscriber".

In RAC 2, a signal outputs events by calling the `sendNext:`, `sendError:`, and `sendCompleted` methods of an object that implements the `RACSubscriber` protocol.  RAC 3 replaces the separate methods with a sink of `Event`s, where an `Event<T,ErrorType>` is an enum that can be one of the cases `.Next(T)`, `.Error(ErrorType)`, and `.Completed`, plus the new `.Interrupted` case.

Wrapping up all the event types in a single enumeration makes it clearer what a signal is all about: it's a stream of events. Events arrive one at a time, and can be one of four types (three in RAC2).  Without swift's `enum` type, those events had to be dispatched separately, since the type of value associated with an event is different for each event type.  With `enum`s that can carry values of different types, all you need to implement `RACSubscriber` is a place to `put` the `Event`, or in other words, a sink.

That still leaves the question of why to bother having a `SinkType` instead of just passing around closures of type `(T -> Void)`. [The docs](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/SinkType/) only really talk about the compiler optimization benefits, but I personally think it's useful because it gives you a name to work with.  If I see a closure of `(T -> Void)`, I have to briefly pause to parse out the types, and if I'm passing them around all the time there's a lot of parens and arrows cluttering up my definitions.

Plus, it's a nice conceptual match if you're working with generators.  Since a RAC `Signal` is conceptually a generator of events, it makes sense to talk in terms of sinks, which are the generator's natural complement.